# Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteAttachment is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web

I am getting an Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteAttachment is not defined when trying to call this function:

```
function deleteAttachment() {
    var node = $("#attachments").fancytree("getActiveNode");
    var key = node.key;
    var folderId = document.getElementById("folderId") ? document.getElementById("folderId").value : "";

    var request = $.ajax({
        url : "attachmentsAjax",
        dataType : "json",
        type : "post",
        data : {
            action : "deleteAttachment",
            "key" : key,
             "folderId" : folderId
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
        <input type="button"  name="deleteAttachment" value="Delete Attachment" onclick="deleteAttachment();" />
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why does this have a Java tag?

Comment: On which line of code does the error occur?

Comment: Is your `deleteAttachment()` function declared in the global scope?  That means it must be at the very top level and not declared inside any other function.

Comment: Ah yes, so I thought it was in the global space, but it wasn't! Once I put it in the global space it worked! Thanks jfriend00!